# No record type in lead

Tags: record-type

I don't get to choose record types in lead object even after I created them. They are already activated. How do I change it so I can choose the Record Type?

Comment: while creating record type there is an option `skip recordType selection` checkbox.. check that

Comment: I have already created the record types. the problem is that I cannot chose a record type when i try to create a lead

Comment: that checkbox  should be unchecked ?

Comment: Also check current user selected default `recordType` for lead? -->setup-->my setting--> Advance details-- >Record Types --> check there

Comment: Also Check current user's profile having how many recordType available for Lead ?